# Javascript, Stop function from logging to console on call

Tags: javascript

Say I have a function imported from a library

```
import doSomething from 'someLibrary';
```

And `doSomething` has a console.log() call inside of it. So, when I call do something

```
doSomething();
```

`Some message` is logged to the console. How do I call the function `doSomething` without it logging anything to the console?

Comment: Not something you can easily do. You can overwrite the global `console.log` with your own custom function that swallows input, but that will nullify any logging from happening including your own.

Comment: If `someLibrary` is open-source on GitHub or similar, reach out to the developer and let them know that is happening. Since `someLibrary` is likely to be in `node_modules` (or similar), it is considered "Vendor Code" and shouldn't be modified directly. Alternatively, make your own "fork" and patch the issue yourself.

Comment: It is the firebase admin-sdk, `admin.auth().updateUser`. If the user email is updated, it logs a link for the user to reset their email to the previous one. I only see this log, however, when called in my tests using the emulator, and not when called on the actual site.

Comment: I was mainly wondering if this is possible to do elegantly, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
    let console = {log: ()=>{}};
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Explain what it does and why it would help OP ;)

Comment: And also the drawbacks of doing this..

Comment: It overwrite console object in local scope, in function doSomething It calls empty function log. Problem may occure if doSomething try to get other console property.